# MFC C++ Class member variable, use instead the constructor with parameter

Tags: c++, mfc

This is MFC C++ (not C++ 0x11).  I have a class, with a member variable of a CDerivedComboBox, call it, CMyForm.  I want to make a constructor for CDerivedComboBox, that passes in a parameter, so when I declare it, I can either pass a flag or not.

For example in .h file, two constructors

```
CDerivedComboBox();
CDerivedComboBox(bool specialFlag);
```

It compiles fine when adding that constructor implementation, but in my class using it, I can't figure out how to actually create one calling that constructor.  Is this not possible in C++/

```
CDerivedComboBox combo; // works
CDerivedComboBox comboParam(true); // does not work
```

Comment: Try `CDerivedComboBox comboParam{true};` (note braces in place of parens). Should work with a sufficiently modern compiler.

Comment: Ah that did work in VS2019 but not VS2008.  Thanks!

Comment: With an insufficiently modern compiler, you'd have to provide the parameter in the constructor initializer list of the containing class. E.g. `class CMyForm { CDerivedComboBox combo; CMyForm() : combo(true) {} };`

Comment: Pre C++11 you can use a more explicit initializer: `CDerivedComboBox comboParam = CDerivedComboBox(true);`.

Comment: Is the `specialFlag` actually a runtime decision? If not, use the type system instead, derive a `CSpecialComboBox` and have an instance of that be your class member. `CSpecialComboBox` knows, that it's special. No need to pass any flags around.

Answer (score -1):

The CDerivedComboBox should be a member of your CMyForm.  It appears you want to dynamically call a different ctor for CDerivedComboBox at runtime.  Therefore, I would recommend making the member be a pointer to a CDerivedComboBox:

```
class CMyForm
{
CDerivedComboBox *m_pMyCombo;
}

CMyForm::CMyForm(..., CWnd *pParent = NULL) : m_pMyCombo(NULL)
{

if (somecondition)
  m_pMyCombo = new CDerivedComboBox();
else  // use specialFlag
  m_pMyCombo = new CDerivedComboBox(specialFlag);
}
```

Remember to `delete m_pMyCombo` in dtor!

Comment: There is next to no reason to ever use `operator new` in C++, and most certainly not a single reason to ever call `delete`.